# Пропадают почему-то все рамки когда пишу last-child{ border:none;}

Tags: html, css

```css
.nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 35px;
    position: relative;  
}

.menu{
    width: 1278px;
    background-color: #4ccfc1;
    padding: 0 120px 0 100px;
}

.menu ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul li{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 25px;
}


.menu ul li:last-child{
    
}
```

```html
     <div class="nav">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul class="punkts-menu">
                <a href=""><li>Home</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Sale</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Handbags</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Wallets</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Accessories</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Mens Store</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Shotes</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Vintage</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Services</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Contact us</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

> The :last-child selector matches every element that is the last child
>   of its parent.

т.е.

> :last-child находит элементы, каждый из которых является последним
>   дочерним элементом в своем родителе.

Соответственно, все `li` элементы в Вашей разметке - последние у своих родителей - тэгов `а`. Надо:

```
.menu ul a:last-child li{
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: ага понял спасибо за ответ